# Can make left join in Entity Framework without dataset

Tags: c#, entity-framework, join

I have this query

```
return _ctx.TestPackages.Where(s => s.Id == TestPackageId).
        Join(_ctx.TestPackageReportDetails, s => s.Id, d => d.TestPackageId, (s, d) => new { reportDetail = d, testpack = s }).
        Join(_ctx.TestPackageReports, p => p.reportDetail.TestPackageReportId, o => o.Id, (p, o) => new { combined = p, report = o })
         .ToList()
```

As you can see my query makes join between 3 tables `TestPackages` `TestPackageReportDetails` and `TestPackageReports`. When I have more than one record in `TestPackageReportDetails` with same `testpackageid`, the result is repeated 3 times in the output. How can I avoid the repetition?

Should I make a left join between TestPackageReportDetails and TestPackages? If yes how can I do that?

Comment: EF is an ORM, not a replacement for SQL Your *entities* should have relations so that you *don't* need to use joins. That means that your `TestPackage` class should have a `Reports` collection `TestPackageReport` should have a `Details` collection. The you could would only have to load the appropriate packages. The rest would be loaded lazily. Or you could add a pair of `Include()` calls to have them load eagerly

Comment: Shouldn't the selector in the last join be the other way around ? Secondly, why aren't  you using the Query-Syntax (`from s in _ctx.TestPackages ....`)  which makes the code clear and readable ?

Comment: In other words you should be able to write `_ctx.TestPackages.Where(s => s.Id == TestPackageId);` or `_ctx.TestPackages.Include("TestPackageReport").Include("TestPackageReport.TestPackageReportDetail"). Where(s => s.Id == TestPackageId);`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos how can i use include ?

Comment: @user3185569 i changed my query .can i write this query with your syntax?

Comment: @user3185569 as you can see in my query i have a function in select syntax .can i use this function in that syntax?

Comment: You can remove **everything** after `ToList`, it's only noise. And yes, as said above, use navigation properties instead of joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're only selecting three fields (As shown before you edit your answer again and remove the select) then you can do this:

```
(from s in _ctx.TestPackages  
join d in _ctx.TestPackageReportDetails, 
on s.Id equals d.TestPackageId
join r in _ctx.TestPackageReports
on s.Id equals r.reportDetail.TestPackageReportId
where s.Id == TestPackageId
select new
{
  s.Id,
  s.packageNumber,
  s.Size,
  s.TestPackageOrder
}).Distinct().ToList().Select(m=> new ..) // continue your normal selection
```

Comment: I get this error :Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String get_Item(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is to Eager load the report details then you should be using .Include :

```
_ctx.TestPackages.Include(t=>t.TestPackageReportDetails.TestPackageReports).Where(s => s.Id == TestPackageId);
```